# Can't create file in Bash on MinGW64

Tags: windows, bash, mingw

Having an executable file in a directory, let's say named hello.exe:

```
$ ls
hello.exe*
```

The file name is colored green and an asterisk is appended.
Listing the file explicitly by giving its name **but without extension**, it is listed without extension:

```
$ ls hello
hello*
```

Until here it looks just like a funny feature for Win freaks that like to omit the `.exe` extension.
But now, when you try to create a file **without any extension**, Bash complains:

```
$ echo hello > hello
bash: hello: Permission denied
```

The same problem arises when you try to copy a folder structure recursively which contains a folder `hello/` and an executable `hello.exe`  in the same folder:
It cannot be copied using `cp -r` when (by accident) the file `hello.exe` is copied first and the folder `hello/` is copied second; the creation of the folder is denied in this case:

```
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory './hello' with directory './hello'
```

Now my question is:
Is this a bug or a feature? If it is a feature, how can I disable it?

The system I'm using is a MINGW64 Bash on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't have a Windows system at hand, but does `echo hello > hello.` in a directory that only contains `hello.exe` behave as intended?

Comment: Windows misfeatures all the way down, I suspect.

Comment: _nod_; it certainly looks to me like an unintended consequence of intended behavior working as designed, but docs are sparse on the ground so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Bash really has no say in this; it's the OS and in particular the weird quirks of the file system which cause this.

Comment: @tripleee I don't believe this is true: on Windows, outside of bash (e.g. in a normal Command Prompt window running the normal cmd.exe), it is indeed possible to create two separate files named "hello" and "hello.exe". It must be mingw that decided to disallow it.

Comment: (quirks of the filesystem _and the portability layer_ adding a shim on top of Microsoft's libc)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes,  `echo hello > hello.`  works.

Comment: I've just detected `ls hello`  (yielding `hello*`)  vs. `ls --append-exe hello` (yielding `hello.exe*`).
Might be there is an env variable for this feature?